# Listen to side menu / hamburger menu clicked event

Tags: codenameone

I would like to detect when a side menu or a hamburger menu is clicked.

Here's the code from a barebone hello world project that doesn't work:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    Toolbar bar = new Toolbar();
    hi.setToolbar(bar);
    bar.addCommandToSideMenu(new Command("test 1"));
    bar.addCommandToSideMenu(new Command("test 2"));
    hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));

    bar.getMenuBar().addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           System.out.println("Side menu or Hamburner Menu is clicked");
        }
    });
    hi.show();
```

I expected when I click the side menu or the hamburger menu to see the string printed. But that was not the case.

How can I listen for a hamburger menu clicked event.

Thanks,

3lix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to disable the side menu icon and just add the button yourself like we did in this template: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/template-mobile-material-screens-ui-kit.html

Comment: I see ! Thats a very interesting approach! Thanks for the help. I think your answer addresses the issue

Answer (score 2):

Since the Toolbar is just a BorderLayout Container on the top of the Form, you can locate the side menu button and add a listener on it.

```
Button sideBtn = (Button)((BorderLayout)bar.getLayout()).getEast();
```

Notice this is an undocumented API so this might break in the future, the side button is not exposed on purpose for a reason, reconsider what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well I don't fully understand why the side button is not exposed at all on purpose. I don't understand why you wouldnt support  listening for opening the side menu event through an api call perhaps. I would reconsider what I am trying to do if  you can direct me to a better approach. In short, I am trying to tint the closing form when a side menu opens and then untint it when the side menu closes.  For tinting / untinting purposes I am filling the rectangle on glassPane. My case is not a show stopper by any means but I like the visual clue hinting that the form is not in focus

Comment: Please let me know if you have any suggestions (better approach to me) or if you think we can maybe in the future provide an API call for this if in fact you see a use case for it that other people may need. I would like to add that I also detect when a menu is opening in order to highlight the last selected option/command in the side menu right before the side menu opens. These are two usual use cases I have so far.

Comment: I think you meant getWest(). I cannot get more than one event. This works the first time around but then stops working: 
Button sideBtn = (Button)((BorderLayout)bar.getLayout()).getWest();
        sideBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               System.out.println("Side menu or Hamburner Menu is clicked");
            }
        });
I started to understand your concerns more right now.  I think the side button also have other events attached to it to open / close the side menu.

Comment: Also, the Menu is actually implemented as a different Form, so trying to place something on the original glasspane could be tricky. It sounds like a feature for the SideMenu itself I would assume this tinting should change it's alpha when dragging as well. I'm afraid this will require some tweaking in the implementation of the side menu, you can file an RFE or fork the project on github implement it and send a pull request

Comment: I would like to point out that, if the side button is not exposed for a reason, then the API should compensate by making a listener available. It's pretty standard for GUI APIs to provide listeners to events like popping up a menu, and it's frustrating that CodenameOne doesn't do this much. The listener approach would also make it easier to rewrite the side menu code without breaking existing apps.

I have also needed to listen to side menu events, and I had to write some kludgy code to get around the design. An API that forces developers to write kludgy code should be rethought a bit.

Comment: Miguel, I dont think they claim to support this feature so that comes with not exposing the API call or the button. And to be honest  this request is an enhancement to the side menu we already have. They say Rome wasn't built in one day but CN1 is becoming more mature by the week from what I see.  Progress takes time and prioritizing is key. Enjoy the ride !